# golang - парсинг xml, результат не сохраняется в структуру

Tags: xml, парсер, golang

Пытаюсь реализовать парсинг xml как в документации golang, но результат не сохраняется в структуру.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "encoding/xml"
)


type Offer struct {
    Url string `xml:"url"`
}


func main() {

xmlFile, err := os.Open("2.xml")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
    return
}
defer xmlFile.Close()

decoder := xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)
total := 0
var inElement string
for {
    // Read tokens from the XML document in a stream.
    t, _ := decoder.Token()
    if t == nil {
        break
    }
    // Inspect the type of the token just read.
    switch se := t.(type) {
    case xml.StartElement:
        inElement = se.Name.Local

        if inElement == "url" {
            var offer Offer
            // decode a whole chunk of following XML into the
            // variable p which is a Page (se above)
            decoder.DecodeElement(offer, &se)

            fmt.Printf("%T", offer)
            // Do some stuff with the page.
            total++
        }
    default:
    }

}

fmt.Printf("Total: %d \n", total)
}
```

Результат {}Total: 1.
Исходный xml

```
<url>hfhfhfhfh</url>
```

Answer (score 0):

Корневой элемент считается уже прочитанным. Так что  в вашем случае можно просто декодировать в `string`. Структура вам понадобится, если элемент находится внутри элемента.

```golang
r = strings.NewReader(`<url>hello</url>`)
err = xml.NewDecoder(r).Decode(&s)
fmt.Println(err, s)
//      <nil> hello

r = strings.NewReader(`<offer><url>hello</url></offer>`)
err = xml.NewDecoder(r).Decode(&o)
fmt.Println(err, s)
//      <nil> hello
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ZegpV-egRLk.